# Efficient way to obtain the mean and standard deviation of a set of arrays in Scala

Tags: scala, performance, mean, standard-deviation

I have a group of n numeric arrays. I need to find the mean and standard deviation of them. I figured out a way using multiple maps, folds and the like, but I wonder if a regular loop would be faster. For example, for the mean I do:

```
 mean = vectors.foldLeft(Array.ofDim[Double](dimensionality)) { (x, y) =>
    (x zip y).map(z => z._1 + z._2)
  }.map(_ / sampleSize)
}
```

Here there are two runs over the arrays, one for the zip and another for the map that sums them. On a regular for loop however, I would only need to traverse each array only once to accumulate the values

Even more for standard deviation. Here I have an awfull way so far

```
sd = vectors.map(x => {
   (x zip _mean).map(z => Math.pow(z._1 - z._2, 2))
  }).reduce((x, y) => {
   (x zip y).map(z => z._1 + z._2)
  }).map(z => z / sampleSize).map(Math.sqrt)
```

Here there are many runs (and I supose that even in a decent solution there would be some too). With a regular for loop, the steps of computing the difference between the value and the mean and then accumulating the value could be done in a single run over each array.

Is there any "Scala" way to achieve this or the loops are just better?

Comment: Can you please share some sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: `flatten` the `Array`, calculate the sum and sum of squares, and then use them to calculate mean and SD. (Google is your friend)

Comment: @GuruStron I have not samples, all I was trying was to find a good way

Comment: @Tim I don't need the mean value or sd of all numeric values, I need the vector (array) that is the mean of those vectors and its corresponding sd

Comment: In which case just `map` the outer array with a simple function to compute the mean and sd of each inner array. Start by writing a function to compute `(mean, sd)` from an array and then just `map` that function onto the outer array.

Answer (score 1):

In terms "Scala" way, you can reduce the number of runs over arrays with [.lazyZip](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterable.html#lazyZip%5BB%5D(that:Iterable%5BB%5D):scala.collection.LazyZip2%5BA,B,Iterable.this.type%5D) if you use 2.13 or `.zipped` if you use 2.12 instead of `.zip`.

```
(x lazyZip y).map(_ + _)
```

It is the same as `.zip` except that the elements in each collection are not consumed until a strict operation is invoked. Thus you is going to have only one run.